# Why is 'this.setState' not working?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching JSON data from an API endpoint and want to use this data to show a table.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
var DeliveryOptionsTHeadTh = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <th>{this.props.label}</th>
    );
  }
});

var DeliveryOptionsTHead = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
      return {
         data : []
      }

  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      this.setState({data: result});
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <DeliveryOptionsTHeadTh label={this.state.data.days[0].label}/>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    );
  }
});

var DeliveryOptionsTable = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <table className='pure-table pure-table-horizontal'>
        <DeliveryOptionsTHead source="<REDACTED>" />
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <DeliveryOptionsTable />,
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

But this returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Why is is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change initial state., as `days` are `Array` of `Objects` and you are trying in `render` method get first element from `Array` but in initial state there is no `days` property, that's why you are getting error

```
var DeliveryOptionsTHead = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      data: { days: [] } 
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      this.setState({data: result});
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    var days = this.state.data.days.map(function (day) {
      return <DeliveryOptionsTHeadTh label={day.label} key={ day.date } />;
    });

    return <thead>
      <tr>{ days }</tr>
    </thead>;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26302/)

Answer (score 1):

It seem you have not declare your initial state, so your react is looking for the data when you called `this.setState({data : result});`
 this should help

```
.....[other react specs code]

getInitialState : function(){
    return {
       data : []
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this but does not work either. Now it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: `this.state.data.days[0].label should be throwing that error when trying to access an object property`.
what does your result return is it a jsonObject or a jsonArray from the http call.